# Azure VM downgrade from A8

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is it possible to downgrade an Azure VM A8 (high compute) to a lower version like an A3?  I keep getting the following error message when I try.  I don't have an availability set setup.  Thanks!

"Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size 'Large' may not be available in the resources supporting the existing deployment. Please try again later, try with a different VM size or smaller number of role instances, or create a deployment under an empty hosted service with a new affinity group or no affinity group binding. The long running operation tracking ID was: b2024fe9e93f6764bec3aa008756f0b7."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered (via MS support tickets) that there are different "clusters" within Azure data centers, with different VM size compatibilities. In my case I had some cloud services in older clusters which didn't allow the newer "D-Series" VM sizes I wanted. The only solution was to create brand new cloud service instances from scratch and use Azure traffic manager to achieve a transition from the old servers to new ones.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I figured out the same thing.  Had to create a new instance.  Thankfully I was able to export the linux image and reimport it into the new VM.

Comment: I've similar question but it's different.