# Downgrading from Azure A-8 instance to A-7

Tags: azure

Need your help in understanding how to downgrade from A-8 instances.
I have 9 nodes in the cluster and all of them are of type A-8. I do not see the option to mix A-8 with A-7/6/5/4/3/2/1 kind of instance types.

If a user creates a cloud service with A-8 instances, user cannot add any instances lower in capacity than A-8. 
If the user creates a new cloud service and add any instances which is lower in capacity than A-8 (A0 to A7), then cloud service does not allow to add A-8 instance in the same cloud service and mandating to have only A-8 across the board.

Since there is no active usage we want to do downgrade to A4.

Generally we can change the instance type form instance name -> configure-> virtual machine size drop down and change the type. But when the instance type is A-8 we don't see the option to down grade.

Is there any work around?

Note : This issue is not related to existing web service. For the existing web service when you try to mix and match other instances you get the error saying the instance type you selected is not supported but when adding you get an option to select the different instance type but here I am not getting an option also.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure VM downgrade from A8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091157/azure-vm-downgrade-from-a8)

Comment: This has already been asked and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091157/azure-vm-downgrade-from-a8

Comment: Thanks Mxa055 to get back but it's not the same issue.

Comment: I believe it is. Have you read https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-a8-a9-a10-a11-specs/ _Additional things to know_ part?  *Likewise, an affinity group with a cloud service that contains A8, A9, A10, and A11 instances can't be used for deployments of other instance sizes.*

Comment: Thanks for believe it :). May be you can remove the link to the existing question.

Comment: Ah does it mean that when we have A8 to A11 instances, we can't downgrade ?

Comment: Exactly! You need to create a new cloud service and migrate your VMs there apparently. Azure FTW

Comment: Based on [my experience](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28097119/251011), this limitation wouldn't surprise me. They apparently have different sets of size options available in different "clusters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we can’t have an A7 or lower spec vm in the same cluster (same Cloud Service) as A8. Because A8 and above are on completely different hardware in different data-centers. Confirmed from various Azure user groups online that its not possible. The only way to do it is to create a new cloud service from scratch.